# WHMCS for subscription based server or alternative

Tags: php

I have been recently looking for a PHP billing system similar to the one used by a lot of webhosts - WHMCS.

What we provide is an online profile for companies to market themselves to their potential audience. To do so there is a fee of £20/m or £200/y. What I really like about WHMCS is that it manages your entire billing side for you.. the issue you I do have with it is that it's strongly related to web hosting, which we aren't. Also it doesn't seem that flexible to fit into our current system.

Does anyone have any advice or suggestions on any similar PHP systems, or whether WHMCS can be edited enough to do what I need it to do?

Thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use a **dedicated recurring billing system** such as these ones:

- [Sassy](http://saasy.com/)
- [Recurly](http://recurly.com/)
- [Spreedly](http://www.spreedly.com/)
- [Chargify](http://chargify.com/)
- [Braintree](http://www.braintreepayments.com/)
- [CheddarGetter](https://cheddargetter.com/)

Note that these don't handle provisioning like WHMCS does -- they are purely payment backends -- so you'd have to code the sign up and activation processes yourself, but custom coding those parts might be more appropriate if you need something more flexible anyway.

Comment: These seem something that more fit what we are looking for, thank you. The only downside to all of these are that they are all hosting solutions, which in turn results in larger payment processing fees in the form of monthly subscriptions + charges. Do you know of any PHP alternatives that can be self hosted, similar to WHMCS with just the billing included?

Comment: @lethalMango - Check [this tutorial](http://www.johnconde.net/blog/tutorial-integrate-the-authorize-net-arb-api-with-php/) from [John Conde's](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/1253/john-conde) blog on using the authorize.net customer information and recurring billing features with PHP. You could also search for "PHP recurring billing script for [PayPal/your payment processor]." It's a good idea to avoid storing customer details and payment information on your own servers whenever you can, which is why I recommend the services above and Authorize.net over self-hosted setups.

Comment: thanks for your advice, I'll go away and have a look over the possible solutions and see where to go now. The alternatives seem to provide more flexibility than WHMCS so looks like that may be the way to go. Thanks :)